# gem install and bundle install fails to install sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, gemfile

I'm new to Rails, and I'm learning it from The Ruby on Rails Tutorial.
The `bundle install` command shows this error when I use `gem 'sqlite3'` in Gemfile;

```
    An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
    succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

I found a solution to this over here - https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b, that suggested that `gem 'sqlite3'` should be replaced with `gem ‘sqlite3’, git: “https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: “add-gemspec”`. On running `bundle install` after upating Gemfile, all the required gems, including sqlite3, appear to have installed;

```
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 70 gems now installed.
Use 'bundle info [gemname]' to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But on running the command `sqlite3 --version`, I still get the error message that says

```
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have also referred to various stackoverflow answers, but none of them seem to work. `gem install sqlite3` is also not working.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried separately installing pre-compiled SQLIte binaries? https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: @rmlockerd, no I haven't. Thank you for the suggestion. Going to try it out.

Comment: @rmlockerd, sorry that didn't work. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: sqlite itself must be installed before you install the ruby gem: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm

Comment: @Sharagoz sqlite3 has installed on my system, but the `rails server` command still returns an error. `bundle info [sqlite3]` also lists sqlite3, and also indicates where it is installed. Is it because I am using  a Windows 10 pc?

Comment: I figured out how to fix it. I just uninstalled Ruby and all the gems (I think i had accidentally messed up one of the files) and then re-installed Ruby. After using `gem install rails` and running the `rails new` command I started the server using the command `ruby bin/rails server`.  @rmlockerd @Sharagoz thank you, using the pre-compiled binaries to install sqlite3 worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try it helped

sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev